# Deploy React APP on Heroku with Two ports

Tags: reactjs, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy my React-Express app on heroku. All steps are clear but I am stuck at a point. My app is using `socket.io` which runs on port `8080` and express app runs on port `process.env`. I want to know how can I deploy my app by single endpoint. When I run the app on single port with socket. I get big delay in socket connection. Most of the time Errors. I am looking for a way for like when `myapp` is asked for then app will run on its port  `socket.io` in my app will run on port i mentioned.

Comment: Did you try following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets#option-2-socket-io

Comment: Yes , I tried it. Not any promising result